# PetePoco new version

Tags: c#, petapoco, micro-orm

I have noticed that the latest commit of petapoco on github https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/  was 10 months ago .
What happening with this product ? What can be considered as appropriate replacement ?

Comment: This might be a good question for the library authors, but probably isn't a good fit here. Also: if it works, what are you looking to see changed?

Comment: Just because it hasn't had a commit in 10 months you want to replace it? Why not fork it and contribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no activity on the project( the patches are not pulled and discussion questions are ignored), I moved to [Servicestack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite). The problem with PetaPoco project is, it is controlled by one person and who does not have enough time to update the project. I think Dapper or Ormlite would be a good alternative.